# vk sharing dollar sign

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vk

I have vk sharing button in my rails app it works great but one tiny problem with `$` sign

my js

```
 javascript:
        document.write(VK.Share.button({
          url: "#{request.original_url}",
          title: "#{@product.title}",
          description: "#{@product.seo_description}",
          image: "#{image_path @product.photos.first.image.url}",
          noparse: true},
          {type:'custom',
          text: "<i class='icon-vk'></i>"}
        ));
```

On preview screen it looks like raw html code `&#036;` 
[image]
Any idea how to fix it? [screen](http://joxi.ru/YmE9XBjfjDzxm6)

Comment: just add `raw` before that

Comment: that text "Only..." is filled in which field? Title?